# Rabbit MQ idle Queue not handling first message

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

We have a RabbitMQ queue that sometimes goes idle.
Whenever we have 2 or more exchanges on this queue, the first one is missing and everything is OK for the others.
It seems like the first one "wakes" the queue up but is not handled correctly.

Is this a normal RabbitMQ way of handling ?

Comment: You would have to put together exact details or a script to reproduce this. There is certainly a bug in how your application is creating entities or using them.